# Write pojo's to parquet file using reflection

Tags: apache, hadoop, serialization, avro, parquet

HI Looking for APIs to write parquest with Pojos that I have.
I was able to generate avro schema using reflection and then create parquet schema using AvroSchemaConverter. 
Also i am not able to find a way to convert Pojos to GenericRecords (avro) else I could have been able to use AvroParquetWriter to write out the Pojos into parquet files.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go through avro you have two options:

1) Let avro generate your pojos (see the tutorial [here](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/gettingstartedjava.html)). The generated pojos extend SpecificRecord which can then be used with AvroParquetWriter.

2) Write the conversion from your pojo to GenericRecord yourself. You can do this either manually or a more generic solution would be to use reflection. However, I encountered difficulties with this approach when I tried to read the data. Based on the supplied schema avro found the pojo in the classpath and tried to instantiate a SpecificRecord instead of GenericRecord. Because of this reason I went with option 1.

Parquet also supports now writing pojo directly. [Here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-parquet-mr/pull/21) is the pull request on parquet github page. However, I think this is not part of an official release yet. In another words, I did not find this code in maven.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions Karolovbrat. I will try these out. 
Ideally i would love to see the pull request released. I see there is Parquet release 2.x coming out

Comment: You can do the following to fix the reader issue that @karolovbrat stated

Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set(AVRO_DATA_SUPPLIER, GenericDataSupplier.class.getName());
ParquetReader<GenericRecord> parquetReader = AvroParquetReader.<GenericRecord>builder(new Path(this.file.getAbsolutePath()))
                .withConf(conf)
                .build();

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: The following code was written when I was in a hurry. It is not efficient and future versions of parquet will surely fix this more directly. That being said, this is a lightweight inefficient approach to what you need. The strategy is POJO -> AVRO -> PARQUET

1. POJO -> AVRO: Declare a schema via reflection. Declare writers and readers based on the schema. At the time of conversion write the object to byte stream and read it back as avro.
2. AVRO -> Parquet: use the AvroParquetWriter included in the parquet-me project.

---

```
private static final Schema avroSchema = ReflectData.AllowNull.get().getSchema(YOURCLASS.class);
private static final ReflectDatumWriter<YOURCLASS> reflectDatumWriter = new ReflectDatumWriter<>(avroSchema);
private static final GenericDatumReader<Object> genericRecordReader = new GenericDatumReader<>(avroSchema);

public GenericRecord toAvroGenericRecord() throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    reflectDatumWriter.write(this, EncoderFactory.get().directBinaryEncoder(bytes, null));
    return (GenericRecord) genericRecordReader.read(null, DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(bytes.toByteArray(), null));
}
```

---

One more thing: it seems the parquet writers are currently very strict about null fields. Make sure none of your fields are null before attempting to write to parquet

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find an existing solution, so I implemented it myself. Here is the link to the implementation: https://gist.github.com/alexeygrigorev/eab72e40c6051e0163a6693054906d66

In short, it does the following:

- uses reflection to get Avro schema from the pojo
- using the schema and reflection it converts pojos to `GenericRecord` objects
- reflection is applied recursively if the pojo contains other pojos or list of pojos