# Converting Java to Avro and back when using kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro

I'm using the confluent platform, 0.9.0.1 and kafka-avro-serializer 2.0.1. Trying to send events to kafka and read them back, I don't see how to turn events back into Java objects. I've read the avro and confluent docs, and there's hints that this is doable, but I can't see to find a good example. Here's my code, I get a GenericData$Record back when I read it with the KafkaConsumer, my question is how to get that back into a Java pojo. I found this [bit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29293177/1138137) of code that I used to serialize the object.

Here's my code:

```
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.io.EncoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectData;
import org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * This is a test...
 */
public class KafkaAvroProducerTest {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(KafkaAvroProducerTest.class);

    @Test
    public void produceAndSendAndEvent() throws Exception {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");
        KafkaProducer producer = new KafkaProducer(props);

        log.debug("starting producer");
        String topic = "topic11";
        Schema schema = ReflectData.get().getSchema(Purchase.class);
        Purchase purchase = new Purchase("appStore", 9.99d, DateTime.now().getMillis(), "BRXh2lf9wm");

        ReflectDatumWriter<Purchase> reflectDatumWriter = new ReflectDatumWriter<>(schema);
        GenericDatumReader<Object> genericRecordReader = new GenericDatumReader<>(schema);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        reflectDatumWriter.write(purchase, EncoderFactory.get().directBinaryEncoder(bytes, null));
        GenericRecord avroRecord = (GenericRecord) genericRecordReader.read(null, DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(bytes.toByteArray(), null));
        ProducerRecord record = new ProducerRecord<Object, Object>(topic, avroRecord);

        Thread producerThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                while(true) {
                    log.debug("send a message {}", record);
                    producer.send(record);
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
            }catch(Exception ex) {
                log.error("error", ex);
            }
        });
        producerThread.start();

        props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("group.id", "testGroup");
        props.put("auto.commit.enable", "false");
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer");
        props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");
        org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer<String, GenericRecord> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer(props);
        kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));

        Thread consumerThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        ConsumerRecords<String, GenericRecord> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(1000);
                        for (ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> record1 : records) {//
                            log.debug("read - {}", record1.value().getClass());
                        }
                    }catch(Exception ex) {
                        log.error("error", ex);
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception ex) {
                log.error("error", ex);
            }
        });
        consumerThread.start();
        System.in.read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I never use Avro, but looking at https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.6/api/java/org/apache/avro/generic/GenericRecord.html why can't you simple populate your POJO manually...

```
class MyPojo {
    public int v1;
    public String v2;
}

// copied from your example code
ConsumerRecords<String, GenericRecord> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(1000);
for (ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> record1 : records) {
    GenericRecord avroRecord = record1.value();
    MyPojo pojo = new MyPojo();
    pojo.v1 = (Integer)avroRecord.get("<fieldname1>");
    pojo.v2 = (String)avroRecord.get("<fieldname2>");

    // process current pojo
}
```

Not sure if this makes sense. If this works, I would move it into a constructor `MyPojo(GenericRecord)`.

Comment: Thanks! Probably will work .I think I was incorrectly thinking avro was like json, in that you can simply serialize and deserialize any pojo. But all the avro examples I see either use the schema along with a maven plugin to generate the class (which is a subclass of SpecificRecordBase), or they use GenericRecord and manually populate the fields like you show. I was hoping to just use an object of my own to serialize, but seems it's not possible. We'll probably go the schema and code gen route, which will help in maintaining compatibility (you can modify the schema as your class changes).

Comment: what is the execution overhead of converting each message ? Is it not happening twice?

Comment: Not sure if I can follow. It's just a conversion from `GenericRecord` into a POJO type. What do you think happens twice?

Answer (score 1):

As likely as the  manually pulling your data out of a GenericRecord serializer into a java class... why write it manually when you can have a reflection lib do it for you?

For automatic conversion to a registered java type you'll be looking at creating your own KafkaAvroDeserializer that creates a SpecificRecord created through a ReflectDatumReader as listed in this stackoverflow post...
- [KafkaAvroDeserializer does not return SpecificRecord but returns GenericRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39606026/kafkaavrodeserializer-does-not-return-specificrecord-but-returns-genericrecord)