# How to deserialize avro data using Apache Beam (KafkaIO)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, apache-beam, confluent-schema-registry

I've only seen one thread containing information about the topic I've mentioned which is :
[How to Deserialising Kafka AVRO messages using Apache Beam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54755668/how-to-deserialising-kafka-avro-messages-using-apache-beam)

However, after trying a few variations of kafkaserializers I still cannot deserialize kafka messages. Here's my code:

```
public class Readkafka {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Readkafka.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Create the Pipeline object with the options we defined above.
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(
                PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create());
       PTransform<PBegin, PCollection<KV<action_states_pkey, String>>> kafka =
                KafkaIO.<action_states_pkey, String>read()
                    .withBootstrapServers("mybootstrapserver")
                    .withTopic("action_States")
                    .withKeyDeserializer(MyClassKafkaAvroDeserializer.class)
                    .withValueDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                    .updateConsumerProperties(ImmutableMap.of("schema.registry.url", (Object)"schemaregistryurl"))
                    .withMaxNumRecords(5)
                    .withoutMetadata();


        p.apply(kafka)
            .apply(Keys.<action_states_pkey>create())
}
```

where MyClassKafkaAvroDeserilizer is

```
public class MyClassKafkaAvroDeserializer extends
AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer implements Deserializer<action_states_pkey> {

@Override
public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
    configure(new KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig(configs));
}

@Override
public action_states_pkey deserialize(String s, byte[] bytes) {
    return (action_states_pkey) this.deserialize(bytes);
}

@Override
public void close() {} }
```

and the class action_states_pkey is code generated from avro tools using

```
java -jar pathtoavrotools/avro-tools-1.8.1.jar compile schema pathtoschema/action_states_pkey.avsc destination path
```

where the action_states_pkey.avsc is literally

```
{"type":"record","name":"action_states_pkey","namespace":"namespace","fields":[{"name":"ad_id","type":["null","int"]},{"name":"action_id","type":["null","int"]},{"name":"state_id","type":["null","int"]}]}
```

With this code I'm getting the error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to my.mudah.beam.test.action_states_pkey
    at my.mudah.beam.test.MyClassKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(MyClassKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:20)
    at my.mudah.beam.test.MyClassKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(MyClassKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:1)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaUnboundedReader.advance(KafkaUnboundedReader.java:221)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.BoundedReadFromUnboundedSource$UnboundedToBoundedSourceAdapter$Reader.advanceWithBackoff(BoundedReadFromUnboundedSource.java:279)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.BoundedReadFromUnboundedSource$UnboundedToBoundedSourceAdapter$Reader.start(BoundedReadFromUnboundedSource.java:256)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources$BoundedReaderIterator.start(WorkerCustomSources.java:592)
    ... 14 more
```

It seems there's an error in trying to map the Avro Data to my custom class ?

Alternatively, I've tried the following code :

```
        PTransform<PBegin, PCollection<KV<action_states_pkey, String>>> kafka =
                KafkaIO.<action_states_pkey, String>read()
                    .withBootstrapServers("bootstrapserver")
                    .withTopic("action_states")
                    .withKeyDeserializerAndCoder((Class)KafkaAvroDeserializer.class, AvroCoder.of(action_states_pkey.class))
                    .withValueDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                    .updateConsumerProperties(ImmutableMap.of("schema.registry.url", (Object)"schemaregistry"))
                    .withMaxNumRecords(5)
                    .withoutMetadata();


        p.apply(kafka);
            .apply(Keys.<action_states_pkey>create())
//            .apply("ExtractWords", ParDo.of(new DoFn<action_states_pkey, String>() {
//                @ProcessElement
//                public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
//                  action_states_pkey key = c.element();
//                    c.output(key.getAdId().toString());
//                }
//            }));
```

which does not give me any error until i try to print out the data. I have to verify that I'm succesfully reading the data one way or another so my intent here is to log the data in the console. If I uncomment the commented section i get the same error once again:

```
SEVERE: 2019-09-13T07:53:56.168Z: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to my.mudah.beam.test.action_states_pkey
    at my.mudah.beam.test.Readkafka$1.processElement(Readkafka.java:151)
```

Another thing to note is that if I specify :

```
.updateConsumerProperties(ImmutableMap.of("specific.avro.reader", (Object)"true"))
```

always gives me an error of

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 443
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Could not find class NAMESPACE.action_states_pkey specified in writer's schema whilst finding reader's schema for a SpecificRecord.
```

It seems there's something wrong with my approach?
If anyone has any experience reading AVRO data from Kafka Streams using Apache Beam, please do help me out. I greatly appreciate it.

Here's a snapshot of my package with the schema and class in it as well:
[package/working path details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDwAq.png)

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be using the Confluent Schema Registry? So why not use their existing Avro deserializers? And if you do, then that isn't compatible with the other deserializer implementation you have... In other words, how was the data actually produced? Using schema registry, or raw Avro data?

Comment: i was in the assumption that im using confluent's deserializers already ?
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer;
this is the Library im using

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what you mean by ' how was the data actually produced? Using schema registry, or raw Avro data? '

I got the schema from the schema registry, compiled it into a java.class, then proceeded

Comment: Sorry, I thought you'd written a different deserializer that wasn't using the registry at first. I think your second approach is correct. I'm not sure why the namespace is being capitalized

Comment: I just masked it. If the second approach is correct, I'm still not able to read the data. Any ideas ?

Comment: I'm confused where you get `my.mudah.beam.test` from since that's not part of the AVSC

Comment: my.mudah.beam.test is my package,
I have the action_states_pkey.avsc which is the schema and the action_states_pkey.java which is the POJO generated from avro tools in my.mudah.beam.test. Hence, I think its trying to cast the avro i've read to the class (action_states_pkey.java)

Comment: I added a snapshot in the question so you can visualise it better

Comment: I can see that, but if you want to create a [mcve], it would be useful if you could not replace your code like `"namespace":"namespace"`, because the error clearly states `NAMESPACE.action_states_pkey` cannot be found, which makes sense if the class name is actually `my.mudah.beam.test.action_states_pkey`...

Comment: Sure. Was trying to mask it for privacy reasons.
Here's the error : Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 443
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Could not find class com.dattran.bottledwater.dbschema.public.action_states_pkey specified in writer's schema whilst finding reader's schema for a SpecificRecord. Im guessing com.dattran.bottledwater.dbschema.public is where the schema is located in the schema registry ?

Comment: The schema would be at `/subjects/action_states-key/version/latest`, by default, but that is unrelated. You can verify `/schemas/ids/443` matches the schema you created your class from, though.

Comment: I've verified the schema is indeed id 443. Here's the schema without the namespace mask: {"schema":"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"action_states_pkey\",\"namespace\":\"com.dattran.bottledwater.dbschema.public\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"ad_id\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"int\"]},{\"name\":\"action_id\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"int\"]},{\"name\":\"state_id\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"int\"]}]}"}. Any ideas on why it's unable to locate the class ?

Comment: Seems to be okay. So, I haven't used Beam, but I do know I've seen that error in other plain Kafka consumer applications, and I don't really know the resolution :/ The error itself just comes from the internal Avro deserialization methods, not really specific to Kafka/Schema Registry. You could try running this same method in a separate class on your own. https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java#L200-L221

Answer (score 0):

> public class MyClassKafkaAvroDeserializer extends
>   *AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer*

Your class is extending the `AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer` which returns `GenericRecord`.

You need to [convert the `GenericRecord` to your custom object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42514352/2534090).

OR

Use `SpecificRecord` for this as stated in one of the following answers:

```
/**
 * Extends deserializer to support ReflectData.
 *
 * @param <V>
 *     value type
 */
public abstract class ReflectKafkaAvroDeserializer<V> extends KafkaAvroDeserializer {

  private Schema readerSchema;
  private DecoderFactory decoderFactory = DecoderFactory.get();

  protected ReflectKafkaAvroDeserializer(Class<V> type) {
    readerSchema = ReflectData.get().getSchema(type);
  }

  @Override
  protected Object deserialize(
      boolean includeSchemaAndVersion,
      String topic,
      Boolean isKey,
      byte[] payload,
      Schema readerSchemaIgnored) throws SerializationException {

    if (payload == null) {
      return null;
    }

    int schemaId = -1;
    try {
      ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(payload);
      if (buffer.get() != MAGIC_BYTE) {
        throw new SerializationException("Unknown magic byte!");
      }

      schemaId = buffer.getInt();
      Schema writerSchema = schemaRegistry.getByID(schemaId);

      int start = buffer.position() + buffer.arrayOffset();
      int length = buffer.limit() - 1 - idSize;
      DatumReader<Object> reader = new ReflectDatumReader(writerSchema, readerSchema);
      BinaryDecoder decoder = decoderFactory.binaryDecoder(buffer.array(), start, length, null);
      return reader.read(null, decoder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new SerializationException("Error deserializing Avro message for id " + schemaId, e);
    } catch (RestClientException e) {
      throw new SerializationException("Error retrieving Avro schema for id " + schemaId, e);
    }
  }
}
```

The above is copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39617120/2534090

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42514352/2534090

Comment: Thanks for the insight, if I already have the schema (.avsc) , how would the code look like ? The code you wrote is if I don't have the schema right ? It get's the schema from the avro data ?

Comment: also i think adding the 
.updateConsumerProperties(ImmutableMap.of("specific.avro.reader", (Object)"true"))
enables it to read as specificrecord ? Or am I mistaken ? 

But I end up with the error
Could not find class NAMESPACE.action_states_pkey specified in writer's schema whilst finding reader's schema for a SpecificRecord.

Comment: @NicholasLeongZhiHao If you have the .avsc file, then you can generate the corresponding POJO file from it using the avro-tools that come packed with apache avro zip file. These POJOs are those which we include in the SpecificRecord. They contain some additional fields and it will not look like a typical POJO which we usually write.

Comment: thanks for the reply. As mentioned, I've already generated the POJO using avro tools. It's name action_states_pkey.java here. Any pointers on how I should proceed with the POJO and the code you suggested ? Much appreciated

Comment: @NicholasLeongZhiHao What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: @NicholasLeongZhiHao You said `Could not find class com.dattran.bottledwater.dbschema.public.action_states_pkey `? in one of your comments, did you include that class at the consumer side?

Comment: 1. If i Have the avsc file, how do I include it in the code you have provided? I can also add the line  .updateConsumerProperties(ImmutableMap.of("specific.avro.reader", (Object)"true")) and it causes the deserializer to return a specific record (not sure about this), but I get the error Could not find class com.dattran.bottledwater.dbschema.public.action_states_pkey. Any ideas ?

Comment: What do you mean include the class at consumer side ?

Comment: Do I have to create a package named 'com.dattran.bottledwater.dbschema.public' and place my POJO which is my action_states_pkey in there ?

Comment: Yes. How are you doing it now? Are you not passing this class as generic type for KafkaConsumer?

Comment: I am not able to create the package due to the reserved word 'public', I just created the class in the same package as my code, I guess that's the problem ? Do we have to rename the namespace then ?

Comment: @NicholasLeongZhiHao you may try it and see if it works. Generally, at consumer side we will give the class name https://github.com/sachabarber/KafkaAvroExamples/blob/44f6bf8e20fa7eb205bed94bf49f4e43926e2f5e/KafkaStreamsSpecificAvro/subscriber/src/main/scala/com/barber/kafka/avro/KafkaDemoAvroSubscriber.scala#L30

Comment: and the generated schema looks like this https://github.com/sachabarber/KafkaAvroExamples/blob/44f6bf8e20fa7eb205bed94bf49f4e43926e2f5e/KafkaStreamsSpecificAvro/common/src/main/scala/com/barber/kafka/avro/UserWithUUID.scala#L1